# Answering interactive questions in bash script

Tags: ssh, bash, shell

I've got a device that supports strange "ssh". It doesn't support key auth an my problem is I don't know how to feed it username and password (-l or user@host are not working). It asks for login and password after connection like this:

```
zeratul@antioch:~$ ssh 1.2.3.4

Please login: user
password : 
Login incorrect
```

Is it even possible to do that from shell script or can I forget it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't support key auth? That's obnoxious...

Comment: Yeah, well seems to be common for Ruckus Wireless devices. I've one of them in very noisy area an sometimes it deadlocks during reconfiguration and I need to reboot it/switch channels manually. I'm trying to automate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is `expect` (it's a package you can install with yum). That's what it's made for.

I've found a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566830/how-do-i-use-expect-to-connect-via-ssh-to-a-system-and-change-the-password-of-th) that should help you or at least guide you in the right direction.